# Would best locations to see X when Y questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So planning a scuba diving trip has got me wondering if questions where someone asks where to see specific animals/plants/natural formations would be on topic, either on a global or national scale?

Comment: Why would it be off topic?

Comment: Lists is what came to mind for this.

Comment: We have the question [Is there a definitive list of the tallest mountains in the world that require little or no mountaineering experience?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/494/is-there-a-definitive-list-of-the-tallest-mountains-in-the-world-that-require-li) which is pretty broad. Your proposal is similar. I think if you limit to one type of X and/or one type of Y you should be fine.  If you ask about all the most interesting stuff in the world in one question it would not be out of scope, but it might be too broad or too opinion based. Just ask you question an see what happens

Comment: And you did [What are good dive sites to scuba dive with cuttlefish?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/what-are-good-dive-sites-to-scuba-dive-with-cuttlefish) and so far it is doing well.

Comment: Aravona, almost all the questions in Charlie's answer are mine! I tried to keep them narrow enough not to trigger the "list" or "too broad" switch. I didn't fully succeed but I didn't end up getting in trouble! My two cents is that your cuttlefish one is specific enough to certain parameters, and it's not overwhelming. It's not like you find a cuttlefish to dive with on every corner, although that would be cool!. We have some outrageous list questions which I don't think should be allowed, but this is different. People seem to like the question and answer, so I hope it's a good sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are on topic, we already have a bunch of these.

- [What is the smallest owl in the world, and where can I see one?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/what-is-the-smallest-owl-in-the-world-and-where-can-i-see-one)
- [Where and when can I see the most seals in Cape Cod, Massachusetts?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/where-and-when-can-i-see-the-most-seals-in-cape-cod-massachusetts)
- [Where do white tigers live?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/where-do-white-tigers-live)
- [What is a lava tube, as a place to see bats? Are there any in the United States?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/what-is-a-lava-tube-as-a-place-to-see-bats-are-there-any-in-the-united-states)
- [How can we see the genetically pure American Bison in Yellowstone National Park?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/how-can-we-see-the-genetically-pure-american-bison-in-yellowstone-national-park)
- [What are good dive sites to scuba dive with cuttlefish?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/what-are-good-dive-sites-to-scuba-dive-with-cuttlefish)

Comment: Ha, ha, all of those except the newest are mine!!